# Docker-compose runs my entrypoint script twice when it should run it once and exit

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**SUMMARY:**

When I run the following command...

```
docker-compose up --build --exit-code-from combined --timeout 600; echo $?
```

My `init.sh` script, which is the entrypoint for my `combined` container, is run twice instead of once. I expect the `init.sh` script to be run only once. **Why is this happening and how can I make it run only once?**

**THE FULL STORY:**

I have two Docker containers:

1. **b-db** - contains my database
2. **b-combined** - contains my web application and a series of tests, which run once the container is up and running.

I'm using a docker-compose.yml file to start both containers.

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/db/Dockerfile
        container_name: b-db
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:     
            - dbdata:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        networks:
            - app-network

    combined:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/combined/Dockerfile
        container_name: b-combined
        restart: unless-stopped
        env_file: .env
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
            - "8080:8080"
        networks:
            - app-network
        depends_on:
            - db

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    dbdata:
    node_modules:
```

Below is the Dockerfile for the `combined` service in `docker-compose.yml`.

```
FROM cypress/included:3.4.1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

RUN npm install -g history-server nodemon

RUN npm run build-test

EXPOSE 8080

COPY ./docker/combined/init.sh /scripts/init.sh

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/scripts/init.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT [ "/scripts/init.sh" ]
```

Below is what is in my `init.sh` file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start front end server
history-server dist -p 8080 &
front_pid=$!

# Start back end server that interacts with DB
nodemon -L server &
back_pid=$!

# Run a specific test
NODE_ENV=test $(npm bin)/cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/analytics_spec.js"

# Error code of the test
test_exit_code=$?

echo "TEST ENDED WITH EXIT CODE OF: $test_exit_code"

# End front and backend server
kill -9 $front_pid
kill -9 $back_pid

# Exit with the error code of the test
echo "EXITING SCRIPT WITH EXIT CODE OF: $test_exit_code"
exit "$test_exit_code"
```

Below is the Dockerfile for my `db` service. All its doing is copying some local data into the Docker container and then initialising the database with this data.

```
FROM  mongo:3.6.14-xenial

COPY ./dump/ /tmp/dump/

COPY mongo_restore.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN chmod 777 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo_restore.sh
```

Below is what is in `mongo_restore.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Creates db using copied data
mongorestore /tmp/dump
```

**When I run the following command...**

```
docker-compose up --build --exit-code-from combined --timeout 600; echo $?
```

**I get the following output:**

```
Building db
Step 1/4 : FROM  mongo:3.6.14-xenial
 ---> 63abac6699cd
Step 2/4 : COPY ./dump/ /tmp/dump/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c63b5bb8a6e6
Step 3/4 : COPY mongo_restore.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 62de88a27f64
Step 4/4 : RUN chmod 777 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo_restore.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 041757bccef5
Successfully built 041757bccef5
Successfully tagged b-property_db:latest
Building combined
Step 1/17 : FROM cypress/included:3.4.1
 ---> 27da0246551c
Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eea587fa33f8
Step 3/17 : RUN npm install -g n
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6ee678f738a0
Step 4/17 : RUN n 9.2.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 27406ead3cff
Step 5/17 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7793be158259
Step 6/17 : RUN npm install npm@6.9.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ec6e4bae63ac
Step 7/17 : RUN rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3cbf0c0c0ec2
Step 8/17 : RUN mv node_modules/npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f92096e43ae1
Step 9/17 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c4b556ca3240
Step 10/17 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2c63f18d836d
Step 11/17 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8b8e1e7bab2b
Step 12/17 : RUN npm install -g history-server nodemon
 ---> Using cache
 ---> da8e46eb02b1
Step 13/17 : RUN npm run build-test
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 424f7171c913
Step 14/17 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ef25e1f0d272
Step 15/17 : COPY ./docker/combined/init.sh /scripts/init.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bd14264aac05
Step 16/17 : RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/scripts/init.sh"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 214afacc9ace
Step 17/17 : ENTRYPOINT [ "/scripts/init.sh" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9ed5241c92f1
Successfully built 9ed5241c92f1
Successfully tagged b-property_combined:latest
Recreating b-db ... done
Recreating b-combined ... done
Attaching to b-db, b-combined
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=3bbb8f5fe956
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.14
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: cbef87692475857c7ee6e764c8f5104b39c342a1
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.229+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true } }
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.230+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.230+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.230+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.230+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.230+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=2466M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),compatibility=(release="3.0",require_max="3.0"),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.882+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1576236450:882897][1:0x7f78cf0bca40], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 70/242560
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:30.960+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1576236450:960786][1:0x7f78cf0bca40], txn-recover: Recovering log 70 through 71
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:31.025+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1576236451:25011][1:0x7f78cf0bca40], txn-recover: Recovering log 71 through 71
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:31.073+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1576236451:73785][1:0x7f78cf0bca40], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:31.111+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:31.111+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:31.111+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:31.111+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:31.113+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:31.114+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
b-combined | [nodemon] 2.0.2
b-combined | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
b-combined | [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
b-combined | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
b-combined | [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
b-combined | history-server listening on port 8080; Ctrl+C to stop
b-combined | raven@2.6.4 alert: no DSN provided, error reporting disabled
b-combined | test
b-combined | server started 5000
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:32.336+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33086 #1 (1 connection now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:32.340+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33086 conn1: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v9.2.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-combined | Mongoose connected to mongodb://db:27017/book-test
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:32.359+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33088 #2 (2 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:32.361+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33088 conn2: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v9.2.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:32.364+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33090 #3 (3 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:32.366+0000 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33090 conn3: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v9.2.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:36.866+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33092 #4 (4 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:36.874+0000 I NETWORK  [conn4] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33092 conn4: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v8.9.3, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:36.874+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33094 #5 (5 connections now open)
b-combined | Mongoose connected to mongodb://db:27017/book-test
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:36.892+0000 I NETWORK  [conn5] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33094 conn5: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v8.9.3, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:36.896+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33096 #6 (6 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:36.897+0000 I NETWORK  [conn6] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33096 conn6: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v8.9.3, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:36.902+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33098 #7 (7 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:27:36.903+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33098 conn7: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v8.9.3, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-combined |
b-combined | ====================================================================================================
b-combined |
b-combined |   (Run Starting)
b-combined |
b-combined |   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
b-combined |   │ Cypress:    3.4.1                                                                              │
b-combined |   │ Browser:    Chrome 75                                                                          │
b-combined |   │ Specs:      1 found (analytics_spec.js)                                                        │
b-combined |   │ Searched:   cypress/integration/analytics_spec.js                                              │
b-combined |   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined | ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
b-combined |
b-combined |   Running: analytics_spec.js...                                                            (1 of 1)
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined |   Analytics
b-combined | (node:212) DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead.
b-combined | (node:212) DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.
    ✓ displays listings on the side bar lazily for upcoming events (6113ms)
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
    ✓ displays listings on the side bar lazily for archived events (3635ms)
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
    ✓ allows the user to click between upcoming and archived (3538ms)
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | (node:30) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-
    ✓ updates prediction and view count (8660ms)
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
    ✓ takes users to the correct routes (7302ms)
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined |   5 passing (30s)
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined |   (Results)
b-combined |
b-combined |   ┌─────────────────────────────────┐
b-combined |   │ Tests:        5                 │
b-combined |   │ Passing:      5                 │
b-combined |   │ Failing:      0                 │
b-combined |   │ Pending:      0                 │
b-combined |   │ Skipped:      0                 │
b-combined |   │ Screenshots:  0                 │
b-combined |   │ Video:        false             │
b-combined |   │ Duration:     29 seconds        │
b-combined |   │ Spec Ran:     analytics_spec.js │
b-combined |   └─────────────────────────────────┘
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined | ====================================================================================================
b-combined |
b-combined |   (Run Finished)
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined |       Spec                                                Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped
b-combined |   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
b-combined |   │ ✔ analytics_spec.js                         00:29        5        5        -        -        - │
b-combined |   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
b-combined |     All specs passed!                           00:29        5        5        -        -        -
b-combined |
b-combined | Mongoose disconnected
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:09.278+0000 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 172.22.0.3:33092 (6 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:09.279+0000 I NETWORK  [conn6] end connection 172.22.0.3:33096 (5 connections now open)
b-combined | Mongoose disconnected through app shutdown
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:09.279+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7] end connection 172.22.0.3:33098 (4 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:09.305+0000 I NETWORK  [conn5] end connection 172.22.0.3:33094 (3 connections now open)
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | TEST ENDED WITH EXIT CODE OF: 0 ===========================
b-combined | EXITING SCRIPT WITH EXIT CODE OF: 0 =====================================
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:09.512+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 172.22.0.3:33088 (2 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:09.512+0000 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 172.22.0.3:33090 (1 connection now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:09.512+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 172.22.0.3:33086 (0 connections now open)
b-combined | [nodemon] 2.0.2
b-combined | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
b-combined | [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
b-combined | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
b-combined | [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
b-combined | history-server listening on port 8080; Ctrl+C to stop
b-combined | raven@2.6.4 alert: no DSN provided, error reporting disabled
b-combined | test
b-combined | server started 5000
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:13.290+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33342 #8 (1 connection now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:13.293+0000 I NETWORK  [conn8] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33342 conn8: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v9.2.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-combined | Mongoose connected to mongodb://db:27017/book-test
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:13.312+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33344 #9 (2 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:13.313+0000 I NETWORK  [conn9] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33344 conn9: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v9.2.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:13.317+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33346 #10 (3 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:13.317+0000 I NETWORK  [conn10] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33346 conn10: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v9.2.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:17.821+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33348 #11 (4 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:17.826+0000 I NETWORK  [conn11] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33348 conn11: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v8.9.3, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-combined | Mongoose connected to mongodb://db:27017/book-test
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:17.843+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33350 #12 (5 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:17.849+0000 I NETWORK  [conn12] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33350 conn12: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v8.9.3, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:17.851+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33352 #13 (6 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:17.851+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33352 conn13: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v8.9.3, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:17.857+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:33354 #14 (7 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:17.857+0000 I NETWORK  [conn14] received client metadata from 172.22.0.3:33354 conn14: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.2.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.125-linuxkit" }, platform: "Node.js v8.9.3, LE, mongodb-core: 3.2.7" }
b-combined |
b-combined | ====================================================================================================
b-combined |
b-combined |   (Run Starting)
b-combined |
b-combined |   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
b-combined |   │ Cypress:    3.4.1                                                                              │
b-combined |   │ Browser:    Chrome 75                                                                          │
b-combined |   │ Specs:      1 found (analytics_spec.js)                                                        │
b-combined |   │ Searched:   cypress/integration/analytics_spec.js                                              │
b-combined |   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined | ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
b-combined |
b-combined |   Running: analytics_spec.js...                                                            (1 of 1)
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined |   Analytics
b-combined | (node:212) DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead.
b-combined | (node:212) DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.
    ✓ displays listings on the side bar lazily for upcoming events (6565ms)
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
    ✓ displays listings on the side bar lazily for archived events (4227ms)
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
    ✓ allows the user to click between upcoming and archived (3456ms)
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | (node:30) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-
    ✓ updates prediction and view count (9194ms)
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | user disconnected
    ✓ takes users to the correct routes (8759ms)
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined |   5 passing (32s)
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined |   (Results)
b-combined |
b-combined |   ┌─────────────────────────────────┐
b-combined |   │ Tests:        5                 │
b-combined |   │ Passing:      5                 │
b-combined |   │ Failing:      0                 │
b-combined |   │ Pending:      0                 │
b-combined |   │ Skipped:      0                 │
b-combined |   │ Screenshots:  0                 │
b-combined |   │ Video:        false             │
b-combined |   │ Duration:     32 seconds        │
b-combined |   │ Spec Ran:     analytics_spec.js │
b-combined |   └─────────────────────────────────┘
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined | ====================================================================================================
b-combined |
b-combined |   (Run Finished)
b-combined |
b-combined |
b-combined |       Spec                                                Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped
b-combined |   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
b-combined |   │ ✔ analytics_spec.js                         00:32        5        5        -        -        - │
b-combined |   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
b-combined |     All specs passed!                           00:32        5        5        -        -        -
b-combined |
b-combined | user disconnected
b-combined | Mongoose disconnected
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:53.042+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13] end connection 172.22.0.3:33352 (6 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:53.042+0000 I NETWORK  [conn11] end connection 172.22.0.3:33348 (5 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:53.042+0000 I NETWORK  [conn14] end connection 172.22.0.3:33354 (4 connections now open)
b-combined | Mongoose disconnected through app shutdown
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:53.065+0000 I NETWORK  [conn12] end connection 172.22.0.3:33350 (3 connections now open)
b-combined | TEST ENDED WITH EXIT CODE OF: 0 ===========================
b-combined | EXITING SCRIPT WITH EXIT CODE OF: 0 =====================================
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:53.204+0000 I NETWORK  [conn9] end connection 172.22.0.3:33344 (2 connections now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:53.205+0000 I NETWORK  [conn8] end connection 172.22.0.3:33342 (1 connection now open)
b-db | 2019-12-13T11:28:53.205+0000 I NETWORK  [conn10] end connection 172.22.0.3:33346 (0 connections now open)
b-combined exited with code 0
Aborting on container exit...
Stopping b-combined   ... done
Stopping b-db         ... done
0
```

**I expect my `init.sh` script to be run once but as you can see from the above output, docker-compose runs my `init.sh` script twice.**

I've pulled out the following snippets from the above output to demonstrate that the `init.sh` script is indeed being run twice:

```
172.22.0.3:33094 (3 connections now open)
    b-combined | user disconnected
    b-combined | TEST ENDED WITH EXIT CODE OF: 0 ===========================
    b-combined | EXITING SCRIPT WITH EXIT CODE OF: 0 =====================================

...

172.22.0.3:33350 (3 connections now open)
    b-combined | TEST ENDED WITH EXIT CODE OF: 0 ===========================
    b-combined | EXITING SCRIPT WITH EXIT CODE OF: 0
```

**Why is this happening and how can I ensure docker-compose runs my init.sh script once?**

Comment: Do you really need the `restart: unless-stopped`? Try removing it, and see if you still get this problem.

Comment: You probably want three separate containers for the history server, backend server, and test driver; maybe even run the test driver outside of Docker entirely.  If one of the two servers crashes then your tests will mysteriously fail but you won't have any indication beyond that.

Comment: @kenny_k yep that was the problem - removed it and now my `init.sh` script runs once. Sigh...the pitfalls of self-learning by copy-pasting from tutorials and not spending the time to understand every single line :( If you'd like, feel free to write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I had that setup initially but I merged my front-end and back-end server into a `combined` container because I realised that my test server would have to address my front-end server as `web:8080` instead of `localhost:8080`, which is problematic since I've only been recently learning docker and I still develop my app natively on my machine instead of in containers. I'm just using Docker to run tests using Jenkins on a remote server right now. Feel free to let me know if you still think I'm "doing this Docker thing" wrong...I'm still very new to this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by removing `restart: unless-stopped` from `docker-compose.yml` file.